# I can't set up an ad-hoc network anymore

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, connection-sharing

I use a windows7 ultimate operating system. For some time i've been unable to set up an ad-hoc network. Each time I try, it displays "Windows could not set up '*NetworkName*' ".
Pls, I need suggestions on how to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Make sure your **wireless hardware switch is turned on**, you can't imagine the relief I got after finding that out.

Answer (score 3):

Did this work and no-longer works? Or has it never worked properly?

That said somethings you should probably know:

- The ad-hoc part of the 802.11 standard (wireless) is very poorly implemented by some wireless network device manufactures
- AdHoc does not support WPA, and many vendors have issues with using WEP on AdHoc
- It might be preferable to use something like [Virtual Router](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) or [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/) which would allow you to make an infrastructure (normal wifi) network using a Windows 7 Host

Comment: AdHoc supports WPA2, get your facts straight. The 802.11-2007 and 2012 standard clearly specifies how to use RSN in IBSS mode. Whether it is implemented is another thing (if you wanna try, Linux supports IBSS RSN on more devices than windows).

Comment: Virtual Router worked instantly after I failed to get my ad-hoc network working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your wireless is on. I kept getting that message again and again until finally I realized that my wireless was off the entire time.

Answer (score 0):

to elaborate slightly - make sure the hardware switch for your wireless is turned on - not just enabling the network adapter in windows - a nice palm to forehead moment for me.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, but I had to let Windows manage the WIFI and not another program such as the ones delivered with the WIFI hardware!